# Detecting if the app is running on the Virtual Android Environment apps like clone app or multi app space

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development

Recently I come across apps like clone app and multi app space. They claim that their apps create an independent virtual operating system on users' devices and also uses secure vpn. I want to detect and block my app to run in these virtual environments.

i tried maintaining package names, digital signatures and all basic things.

Comment: It is hard to believe that app names dont start with a capital.